# AngularJS couldn't find specific item from mongodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on a MEAN stack application, course manager, which can add, delete, edit, and save classes.  I met a problem with my edit function part. when I call updateCourse() function, the chrome show this error: 
angular.js:7772 PUT http://localhost:3000/courses/5807a8a8542607e01aaf1eb5 404 (Not Found) I can find this ID: 5807a8a8542607e01aaf1eb5 in my MongoDB,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5807a8a8542607e01aaf1eb5"),
    "courseName" : "web development",
    "courseID" : "cs 602",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2016-10-19T17:08:56.226Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

but angular can not get it.
I think my node.js part and data base part works fine, because I use Advanced REST tested http://localhost:3000/api/courses in PUT way, it give me 200:OK. However, the angular part, I have no idea what happened. If anyone can help, thank you so much in advanced. Here is my code: 
Angular Part:

```
$scope.updateCourse= function (course) {
       $http.put('/courses' + course._id,{courseID: course.updatedCourseId,
       courseName:course.updatedCourseName}).success(function(response){
           $scope.courses = courseService.query();
           course.isEditing = false;
       });
```

Node.js Part:

```
router.put('/courses/:id',function (req,res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(req.body);
    Course.update({_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)},{
        $set:{courseID: req.body.courseID,
              courseName: req.body.courseName}
    },function (err) {
        if (err) {console.log(err);}
        res.send("Updated");
    })
});
```

MongoDB part:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    courseID: String,
    courseName: String,
    isEditing: Boolean,
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema);
```

Comment: Should it be `'/courses/' + course._id`?

Comment: hello @ExplosionPills I tried, but doesn't work neither. Thank you though.